# Finding Volume of Revolution with Multivariate Calculus

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, volume

For some function $f\left(x\right)$
  it is possible to rotate it along the x-axis and find the area using

$$\intop_{a}^{b}\pi\left(f\left(x\right)\right)^{2}dx$$

I'm curious how to do this with multivariate calculus. If I represent this in a parametric form, like

$$g\left(t\right)=\left(t,f\left(t\right),0\right)$$

and then rotate using

$$\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & cos\:\theta & -sin\:\theta\\
0 & sin\:\theta & cos\:\theta
\end{array}\right]$$

The result is

$$\varPsi\left(t,\theta\right)=\left(t,f\left(t\right)\left(cos\:\theta\right),f\left(t\right)\left(sin\:\theta\right)\right)$$

over $a\leq t\leq b$
  and $0\leq\theta\leq2\pi$
 .

I think to compute the volume, I need to use the double-integral

$$V = \iint\left\langle \begin{array}{cc}
\frac{\partial\varPsi}{\partial t} & \frac{\partial\varPsi}{\partial\theta}\end{array}\right\rangle \partial t\partial\theta$$

where I'm using $\left\langle \right\rangle$
 for matrix determinant out of simplicity (and leaving out the bounds).

I can find

$$\frac{\partial\varPsi}{\partial t}=\left(1,f'\left(t\right)\left(cos\:\theta\right),f'\left(t\right)\left(sin\:\theta\right)\right)$$

and

$$\frac{\partial\varPsi}{\partial\theta}=\left(0,f\left(t\right)\left(-sin\:\theta\right),f\left(t\right)\left(cos\:\theta\right)\right)$$

But the problem is that they would get put in a $3\times2$
  matrix, so it doesn't make sense to take the determinant.

So I think I am doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You still need $r$ because it can be anywhere inside the surface

$\Psi(t, r,θ)=(t,r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)$
$$\iiint \left\langle \begin{array}{cc}
\frac{\partial\varPsi}{\partial t} &\frac{\partial\varPsi}{\partial r}& \frac{\partial\varPsi}{\partial\theta}\end{array}\right\rangle \,dr \,d\theta\, dt$$

And then the limit of $r = f(t).$

$$\int_a^b\int_0^{2pi}\int_0^{f(t)} r \,dr \,d\theta\, dt$$
$$\int_a^b \pi f^2(t) dt$$